# ALSA configuration to record separate channels

Tags: alsa

I have a ALSA sound card which delivers 16 channel TDM audio. I need to record audio on a particular channel alone (for each channel).
Whenever I try to record on channel 1, I'm getting the audio with too much of noise. The verbose log shows that the ALSA plugin is accumulating data from all 16 channels. As given in below log,

```
Plug PCM: Route conversion PCM (sformat=S16_LE)
  Transformation table:
    0 <- 0*0.0625 + 1*0.0625 + 2*0.0625 + 3*0.0625 + 4*0.0625 + 5*0.0625 + 6*0.0625 + 7*0.0625 + 8*0.0625 + 9*0.0625 + 10*0.0625 + 11*0.0625 + 12*0.0625 + 13*0.0625 + 14*0.0625 + 15*0.0625
```

When I tried to record on the channel 2, getting below log but there is no audio, only noise present.

```
Plug PCM: Route conversion PCM (sformat=S16_LE)
      Transformation table:
        0 <- 0
        1 <- 1
```

My asound.conf looks as given below,

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "playback"
    capture.pcm "capture"
}

pcm.playback {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmixed"
}

pcm.capture {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "recorder"
}

pcm_slave.vrmaudio {
    type hw
        card 0
    device 0
    channels 1
    rate 16000
    format S16_LE
    chmap [ Mono ]
}

pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    slave {
            pcm "hw:0,0"
            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_size 4096
        rate 16000
        format S16_LE
    }
    ipc_key 555555
    ipc_perm 0666
}

pcm.recorder {
    type dsnoop
    slave vrmaudio
    ipc_key 666666
    ipc_perm 0666
}
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Have you tried *arecord* on the device/sub device as listed in arecord -l ?

Comment: @MC68020
Yes, I tried. The result is as given below,
`root@imx8mm-var-dart:~# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: vrmaudio [vrm-audio], device 0: Audio snd-soc-vrm-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

root@imx8mm-var-dart:~# arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=vrmaudio
    vrm-audio,
    Default Audio Device`